# Splitting a List of integers into a tuple of lists

Tags: f#, ocaml

Wasted a few hours trying to accomplish this task in OCaml **but can't figure out the syntax error.**

```
let split l =
  let rec split1 (l1, l2) accu = 
    match (l1, l2) with
    | xs, ([] | [_]) -> (accu, xs)
    | [], _ -> ([], [])
    | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> split1 (xs, ys) x::accu
  split1 (l, l) [];;
```

I get Syntax error on line 7, characters 20-22

**But the analogous code in F# compiles and executes fine:**

```
    let split (l :int list) =
      let rec split1 (l1 :int list, l2 :int list) (accu :int list) = 
        match (l1, l2) with
        | xs, ([] | [_]) -> (rev accu, xs)
        | [], _ -> ([], [])
        | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> let t = x::accu in split1 (xs, ys) t
    split1 (l, l) [];;
```

Running in F# on [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;1;2;34;5;6] list

I get the result:

([1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7], [8; 9; 1; 2; 34; 5; 6])

I'm using Web based TryOcaml (v. 4.01.0)

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let split (l :int list) =
      let rec split1 ((l1 :int list), (l2 :int list)) (accu :int list) =
        match (l1, l2) with
        | xs, ([] | [_]) -> (List.rev accu, xs)
        | [], _ -> ([], [])
        | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> let t = x::accu in split1 (xs, ys) t
      in
    split1 (l, l) []
```

Or

```
let split l  =
      let rec split1 (l1, l2 ) accu  =
        match (l1, l2) with
        | xs, ([] | [_]) -> (List.rev accu, xs)
        | [], _ -> ([], [])
        | x::xs, y::y'::ys -> split1 (xs, ys) (x::accu)                   
      in
    split1 (l, l) []
```

Test :

```
# split [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;1;2;34;5;6];;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7], [8; 9; 1; 2; 34; 5; 6])
```